# Install on to Toshiba Satellite Pro

Tags: installation, toshiba-satellite

I applogise in adance for the crudeness of this message

I have been handed a Toshiba Satellite Pro C850-1C3 which has had it's windows 8 accidentally deleted (hard drive is presumed blank).

I was hoping to burn the .iso (following the instructions found on the website) and install Ubuntu, but when I put the disk in and start up I just get No bootable device - restart computer. Now I have changed the BIOS but I still get the same error.

Help!

Comment: How are you burning your ISO?

Comment: Through the Disk utility on my mac I drag the image over to the panel burn the Image there, the CD will mount in my virtual computer but not the Laptop.

Comment: I think I solved it seems I downloaded the wrong image type 32 bit instead of 64 it is working fine at this point. 

Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select the startup device, this is usually done by pressing F12 at startup on most Toshiba units, sometimes it needs to be enabled in the bios. 
Others you need to hold 0 as you start it, whichever it requires you will need to select the external media you need to boot from.

Comment: The OP says that they have changed the BIOS

Comment: Hey Tom I have given that a try I get 4 options I select the DVD drive that the .iso image is on and I still get the same response. I have selected the ODD MATSHITADVD-RAM UJ8C0 (PM) rom the menu I presume this is right

Comment: Sounds right, the ISO might not be burnt properly; instead of dragging it onto the drive (which is probably copying the iso rather than extracting) use the 'restore' option in disk utility instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you have changed your BIOS, it can only be a couple of things,

1. The method you burned your CD didn't close the session
2. The CD didn't take the image properly.

I suggest  that you download another copy of the iso from the [Ubuntu Website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and burn the image to a new CD/DVD.

This then becomes a LiveCD which should be bootable.

Comment: I am currently running a iMAC to download and burn the .iso to a DVD, then following the guide for proper .iso burning I burn the image. Could this be a source of error?